# Make a variable with a fixed value

Tags: ios, variables, fixed

I've a view controller with one variable `x`, in ViewController.h:

```
@property(nonatomic) int x;
```

Is it possible to set the recent value of `x` fixed? For example a method sets `x` to the value 5 and when this view controller is reloaded the value of `x` should be 5 and not 0 again as it is now.

e.g. in a ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender {
_x++;
}
```

x should be increase after each tapping of the button >>> 0,1,2,3,4...(even after a restart of the app)

Thanks to all your answers in advance.

Comment: Reloaded how? Do you want to persist the value of the property across application restarts? Are you looking for `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple and clear methods to store your value.

Your **interface**:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) int x;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
- (void)updateLabel;

@end
```

Your **setter**:

```
- (void)setX:(int)x
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setInteger:x forKey:@"MyValue"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Your **getter**:

```
- (int)x
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults integerForKey:@"MyValue"];
}
```

Your **action**:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    [self updateLabel];
    self.x++;
}
```

Your **viewDidAppear:** method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateLabel];
}
```

Your method to **update label**:

```
- (void)updateLabel
{
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.x]];
}
```

**Notes**:

1. @"MyValue" has to be unique string, because UserDefaults is only
   instance for whole application.
2. integerForKey is method to store int
       values only.

**Updated**: I'm sorry, integerForKey is right method here, thanks to @**JoshHinman**.

Comment: Replace `objectForKey` with `integerForKey`.

Comment: Is it also possible to have access to it in an other view controller? For example:    `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *viewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
    
    viewController.x = 0;`
 I tied this but it doesn't work

Comment: @Bob I have just corrected my answer to use it way you want. It will works perfect.